# How to make a select with a limit by time of execution

Tags: mysql, select

How to make a select with execution time limit? - It needs to return the loaded data until timeout.

```
Select * from table limit timeout 10 seconds
|
|
|
After 10 seconds
- Only 502 queries were loaded
```

Return these 502 queries and END mysql execution because of timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this can help you

```
con.query('SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800')
```

Comment: Does this settings return the loaded rows until timeout?

Comment: in file php.ini find this  mysql.connect_timeout=3

Comment: It does not return data

Comment: So it is not what I need